# input length = value length & expands automatically according to value length

Tags: html

I want  value length to be the same length as input field and expand automatically. When i write in some text it always has right or left free space. I don't want to define input size, i just want it to be the size of the text.

Can this be done ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use javascript for doing this. Using pure HTML this can't be done. On `change` event of the text field, you can find the length of the text and the width/size and resize accordingly. [Here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=32854) is sample code.

Comment: this code looks very bad written if it needs soo many lines for such simple task